# How to call Flutter Widget from Flutter project to Native Android to bind in Service?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-method-channel

I'm working on a project where I have the requirement to bind the Flutter Widget to Native Android Service class and in the place of LayoutInflater. I've already worked on the method channels concept, but this is completely different story.

Need some help on this.

Comment: I hope you are trying to find this https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app

Comment: Not exactly, that example explaining to add a flutter module to Native Android app. But I want to bind the Flutter widget into Native Android Service Class. Please read the question carefully. @UsamaKarim

Comment: Here I found one article, I don't know whether it will work for you or not : https://blog.canopas.com/add-flutter-view-to-native-android-application-3747edb83e62

Comment: @PratikButani Thanks for the article, but that approach will be a cost effective. Here, I want to achieve only to bind one widget for ex: FAB button inside Android Service class. Instead of render the xml layout in Service class using LayoutInflater, I want to bind the Flutter Widget.